# How to compute a reasonable number of bits for a checksum?

Tags: hash, probability, checksum, sha

I have around 1500 bytes of data that I want to construct a checksum for so that if the data gets corrupted the chances of the checksum still matching the data is less than say 1 in 10^15, i.e. a low enough probability that I can treat it as it is never going to happen.

The question is how many bits should I compute?  I have a sha-160 computation that gives me a 160 bit hash of my data, but I expect this is way larger than necessary.  So I'm thinking I could truncate the resulting hash down to say the low 40 bits and use that as a sufficiently large bit pattern that if the data gets corrupted, I will most likely detect it.

So the question is two fold, how many bits is good enough and is taking the lower bits of a sha-160 hash a good approach to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the table [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack#The_mathematics) to determine approximately how many bits you need for your desired error detection rate.